# Laravel does not pass error to Ajax on form request error

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3

When posting something to a laravel controller using a custom form request, the error is not given back to the ajax call.

The code in the 'error' part is never executed, the error is only shown in the console, without any error messages i specified in the request validation.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

This is my ajax request

```
  var data = {
            'description' : $("#shiftdescription").val()
        };

 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ env('APP_SITE', 'http://localhost:8000') }}/shifts/store",
                content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#shiftdetails").html(response);
                },
                error: function(response){
                    var errors = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                    console.log(errors);
                    // Render the errors with js ...
                }
            });
```

this is the form request

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        'description'   => 'required|string|min:5'
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'description.required'    => trans('crud.description').' '.trans('error.required'),
    ];
}
```

I am getting this error
[image]

**edit 1 - view code**

```
<div class="modal-body">
<form>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group input-field col m2 l2 shiftform">
            {{ Form::text('description', null, array('id'=> 'shiftdescription', 'class'=>'validate', 'placeholder' => trans('crud.description'))) }}
            {{$errors->first('description', '<span class=error>:message</span>')}}
        </div>
        <a href="#!" onclick="nextshift_1()">Volgende stap</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller

```
 public function store(Requests\StoreShiftRequest $request)
{
        $shift = new Shift();
        $shift->description = $request['description'];
...
```

Comment: Please show the content of the page where you have the error(ust click http://localhost:8000/shifts/store).

Comment: @JanWytze, I added the view. The value of 'description' is sent correctly to the request.

Comment: Can you show me the actual response of the request?

Comment: The error shown in the picture is the only kind of response I get.

Comment: So the response returned is empty? There should be some kind of error message. Just click the url in the error and take a screenshot of the page you get. Also check the error log and check if your request left an error in the log

Comment: if you are using AJAX then you have to get error on json format and print through loop